# how to combine first name and last name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
**"error"
"TypeError: Person.fname is not a function
    at Person.fullname (hovaqedile.js:14:17)
    at hovaqedile.js:19:40
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.1.4.min.js:1:13924
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.1.4.min.js:1:10866**
```

hi

how to combine first name and last name in javascript ? I am getting error

```
function Person(){

}

Person.prototype.fname=function(){
  return "abc"
}

Person.prototype.lname=function(){
  return "lop"
}

Person.prototype.fullname=function(){
  return Person.fname() + Person.lname()
}

var p = new Person();

console.log(p.fullname())
```

can you please tell how I will print call first name and lastname in javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `this` keyword which is a **reference** to the current object.

```js
function Person(){

}

Person.prototype.fname=function(){
  return "abc"
}

Person.prototype.lname=function(){
  return "lop"
}

Person.prototype.fullname=function(){
  return this.fname() + this.lname()
}

var p = new Person();

console.log(p.fullname())
```

Comment: The second solution is only working because the `fname` and the `lname` are constant for all the instances of `Person` but if you make them dynamic, it won't work anymore. Creating new instances inside the own instance is a bit weird. I recommend the first solution.

Comment: @miquelarranz, yes, i removed it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `this` when using `prototype` structure in the function. This is because the `this` will take the scope of the entire function `Person` while using the `prototype` structure. Also, use a whitespace between your `fname` and `lname`.

```js
function Person(){

}

Person.prototype.fname=function(){
  return "abc"
}

Person.prototype.lname=function(){
  return "lop"
}

Person.prototype.fullname=function(){
  return this.fname() + ' '+  this.lname()
}

var p = new Person();

console.log(p.fullname())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `this`. I'd do some deeper reading about it, as it's an incredibly useful piece of the language. Take a look at the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) on it.

In your code:

```
Person.prototype.fullname = function() {
  return this.fname() + this.lname();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var Person = {
      firstName: ‘John’,
      lastName: ‘Smith’,
      fullName: function (){
          this.fullName = this.firstName 
          + ‘ ‘ + this.lastName;
      }
};
Person.fullName();
console.log(Person.fullName);
```

Comment: It would be preferable to add some explanation to your code-only answer, especially since you're making drastic changes to the provided code. Also, your quotation marks are incorrect.

Comment: I am concatenating two properties to a new property, fullName; firstName + lastName = fullName. ‘fullName’ is both method and a property.  ’this’ allows you to access the properties in the current object.  ’this.fullName’ stores the concatenation and creates a new property in the object Person. I then call the method; Person.fullName(), this populates the first and last names into the new property fullName.

Answer (score 0):

`Person.fname()` is not a function because you have to reference the instance when calling a function of the instance. `Person` is the prototype. You can do it using `this` (which refers to the instance in this case -> more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)) instead of `Person`

```
Person.prototype.fullname = function() {
  return this.fname() + this.lname();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addFullNameProperty(obj) {
  
   obj.fullName = obj.firstName + ' ' + obj.lastName;
  
  return obj.fullName;

}
```

Comment: Not super useful if first/last name changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the easiest solution.

```
    const firstName = 'Amir';
    const lastName = 'Khan';
    function fullName(firstName,lastName){
        return firstName.concat(' ').concat(lastName);
    }
    console.log(fullName(firstName,lastName));
```